# How to convert WAR application into console application (Making Unicorn has console application)

Tags: java, web-applications, console-application, unicorn

Unicorn just provide a URI and push the button. It will call a series of validation services and report the results.I have already downloaded and installed Unicorn.
To Download the source code it is only available for download from the  Mercurial repository. To download it, use the command "hg clone https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/unicorn"

To compile Unicorn, Apache Ant and Ivy are required. 
From Unicorn's directory, run: "ant retrieve generate_observer generate_tasklist default_conf war"

It works fine in apache-tomcat, what I want is how to make the unicorn as console application.
The input should passed through command line arguments and output should displayed at console itself I don`t want to use any web server to deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

Make your war a runnable jar too.  Just requires adding a Class-Path entry to the Manifest and having a static main(...) to invoke.

Have a look at Hudson which is distributed in a WAR-file which can be invoked with "java -jar" to bootstrap itself.

Comment: Can be describe the process of doing it because I don`t have that much knowledge I used to do simple exercise so please write me the steps to implement it.Thank u for the concern.

Comment: I just did.  You may need more practice before undertaking this task.  I would suggest The Java Tutorial for further learning.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that you have a major programming exercise on your hands.  A typical web-based application and a typical console based application are structured very differently.  Even the output format is different; i.e. HTML markup versus plain text.

Comment: We need a web browser to deploy a war so what if we have console web server Is is any console web server available? Thanks for the concern